# Periodically download file from web to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My website is hosted on a S3 bucket.

**I need to periodically (every minute or less) download a file from a distant website (via HTTP) and put it in my bucket.** +make some text edit on it if possible.

I do not have any AWS EC2 instance ruining to do that (and that would be to much money for me to run one 24/7). I was thinking AWS Lambda was the best service to do it but I didn't manage to do periodic tasks.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: AWS now provides periodic lambda functions: [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29)

Answer (score 1):

There are few online cron job providers like https://www.easycron.com/. There you can schedule a job to run periodically and they run for you that job forever.

I assume you know cron jobs. So I think this will be best option for you.

Comment: This service allow to call a script periodically but I still need a server to run it

Comment: yes, you'll need a server. a t2.micro is $10/month.